# What is a category of "Lepagean equivalent" or "variation problem"?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory

I get to know about it form Mark Gotay's work ***An exterior differential system approach to the Cartan form***, in that paper he defined the canonical Lepagean equivalent. The following is cited from it:

A **canonical Lepagean equivalent** of a variation problem $\left( M\stackrel{\pi}{\longrightarrow} X, \mathcal{I}, \mathcal{L} \right)$ is another variation problem $\left( W\stackrel{\rho}{\longrightarrow} X, \left\{0 \right\}, \Theta \right)$, together with a surjective submersion $\nu:W \longrightarrow M$, such that: (1) $\rho=\pi\circ\nu$, and (2) if $\gamma \in \Gamma \left(\rho\right)$ satisfies $\nu\circ\gamma\in\Gamma \left(\pi,\mathcal{I}\right)$, then

$\gamma ^{*}\Theta=\left(\nu\circ\gamma\right)^{*}\mathcal{L}$

$\Theta$ is a Lepagean equivalent of $\mathcal{L}$ if

$\Theta\equiv\nu^{*}\mathcal{L} $ mod $\nu^{*}\mathcal{I}$

And in the paper he said that the assignment $\left( M\stackrel{\pi}{\longrightarrow} X, \mathcal{I}, \mathcal{L} \right) \rightsquigarrow \left( W\stackrel{\rho}{\longrightarrow} X, \left\{0 \right\}, \Theta_{\mathcal{}} \right)$ is an affine functor from the **category of constrained variation problems** to the **category of free ones**. This is a welcome feature of the canonical Lepagean equivalent, as classical Lepagean equivalents are not functorial in general (why?).

I'm interested in the category feature of such variation problems, what are the objects, what are the arrows, is the functor invertible, why are classical Lepagean equivalents not functorial in general, is there any specified research about it?

Comment: It's ok, I figure out it myself.